# Problem in calculating all differences between features of data and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose that we have some data that contain features for the sample numbers `0,1,2,...,9` and a list `y` that contains the labels of `0,1,...,9` that correspond to each raw of data.These data have dimensions `(2006,256)` where `256` are the features and `2006` the samples numbers.

Also we are given the means of `0,1,2,...,9` as `v0,v1,v2,...,v9`, where each `v0,v1,...,v9` has dimension `(1,256)`.

I would like to calculate the euclidean difference between all the `2006` sample and `v0,v1,v2,...,v9` in order to make classification.

In order to do that I have to take the difference between features and `v0,v1,v2,...,v9` for each sample.For example for sample `1` I have to take the difference of `256` features with `v0`, then with `v1`  etc. and then find the `min` difference.

I define `ListV=[v0,v1,v2,...,v9]`
and my code is

```
diff=[]
ListV=[v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9]
for j in range(0,10):
    i=np.where(y==j)
    for k in range(0,len(i[0][:])):
        for l in range(0,9-j):
            diff.append(distance.euclidean(ListV[j+l],data[i[0][k],:]))
```

but this code leaves out many euclidean differences.

I would like some help in order to fix that and find all the differences.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred for me once. On that case I had null data in my data-set, be sure your data have defined and real values.